# Functional Interface Object Cast

Tags: java, functional-programming, functional-interface

I've encountered the following code in a Java project, and I'm not sure what to make of it:

```
public Function<CustomEnum,String> foo(SomeObject someObject) {
    return ((Function<CustomEnum,String>) (someObject::toString)).andThen(r -> someObject::getSomethingWithEnumParameter);
}
```

I don't really understand how you can cast something to a Functional Interface. What does that even mean?

Isn't the resulting type of the return value going to be whatever value someObject.

Isn't `Function<CustomEnum, String>` defining an anonymous function that takes a type `CustomEnum` and returns a `String`?

I've read the java doc for `Function<T,R>`, and to be honest, this doesn't make much more sense than before I read the document.

This is what I believe is happening.

1. foo is returning an anonymous function that is applied to some `CustomEnum` to return a String
2. the anonymous function inside of foo (which is somehow cast onto `someObject::toString`, which I don't understand) is applied to the `CustomEnum` that will be passed from the initial call of `foo(someObject).apply(customEnum)`.
3. The `andThen` will take the resulting String from the anonymous function inside of foo (which was cast somehow I still don't understand), and then return the value of `someObject::getSomethingWithEnumParameter`. Why isn't the return type just the type of `someObject::getSomethingWithEnumParameter`, which we'll say is a `Map<R,T>`, for sake of discussion.

If anyone could help me understand this flow, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That code is obnoxious and if that developer were on my team, I’d have a serious talk with him/her.  The right way to accomplish that is to create a separate method whose body is `return someObject.getSomethingWithEnumParam(someObject.toString());`, so a simple reference to that method can be used as a function.

Answer (score 2):

In an ideal world this would work:

```
public Function<CustomEnum,String> foo(SomeObject someObject) {
    return (someObject::toString).andThen(...);
}
```

However Java needs an interface type in order to implicitly create an interface instance from the method reference., hence the explicit cast is required to cast to the Function interface type.

Once you have an instance of Function then you can call any method on it as per normal, in this case the `andThen` method which composes it with another function object to form a new function.

Breaking it down:

`someObject::toString` is a method reference with implied type `Function<CustomEnum, String>`. I.e. `toString` is a method on `SomeObject` which takes a parameter of type `CustomEnum` and returns a `String`.

`r -> someObject::getSomethingWithEnumParameter` has the wrong type though - it's a function which returns a function. If you get rid of the "`r ->`" part then it is valid, as long as `someObject::getSomethingWithEnumParameter` is a method on `SomeObject` that takes a `String` and returns a `String`. Alternatively the return type of `foo` would need to change to `Function<CustomEnum, Function<String, String>>`.

If you combine those two with `andThen` then you have a `Function` which takes a `CustomEnum` and returns a `String`, as pr the return type of `foo`.